# Best way to update config file in Docker with environment variables

Tags: docker

im unable to find an easy solution, but probably i'm just searching for the wrong things:

I have a docker-compose.yml which contains a tomcat that is built by the contents of the /tomcat folder. In /tomcat there is a Dockerfile, a .war and a server.xml.

The Dockerfile is based on tomcat:9, and copys the server.xml and .war files into the right directories.

If I do docker-compose up, everything is running fine. But i would love to find a way to update the connectors within the server.xml, without pruning the image, adjusting the server.xml and start it again.

It would be perfect to put a $CONNECTOR_CONFIG in the server.xml, and provide an variables.env to docker-compose where the $CONNECTOR_CONFIG variable is set to like ""

I know i could adjust the server.xml within the Dockerfile with sed, but this way the image must be pruned everytime i want to change something right?

Is there a way that i can later just edit the variables.env and docker-compose down/up?

Regards,
EdFred

Comment: The Docker approach is not to "update" running containers, but rather to restart them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful pattern here is to use the image's `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script that does first-time setup.  If that script ends with `exec "$@"` then it will execute the image's `CMD` as normal.  You can use this to do things like rewrite configuration files based on environment variables.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh

# Replace any environment variable references in server.xml.tmpl.
# (Assumes the image has the full GNU tool set.)
envsubst <"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml.tmpl" >"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml"

# Run the standard container command.
exec "$@"
```

Normally in a `tomcat` image you wouldn't include a `CMD` since the base image knows how to start Tomcat.  The [Docker Hub `tomcat` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) has a mention of it, or you can click through to find the original Dockerfile.  You need to know this since specifying an `ENTRYPOINT` in a derived Dockerfile will reset the `CMD`.

Your Dockerfile then needs to `COPY` this script in and set up the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM tomcat:9
COPY myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY server.xml.tmpl /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/

# ENTRYPOINT _MUST_ be JSON-array form
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
# Duplicate from base image
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

You can verify this by hand using a `docker run` command.  Any command you specify after the image name gets run instead of the `CMD`; but the main container command is still constructed by passing that command as arguments to the alternate `ENTRYPOINT` and so your wrapper script will run.

```sh
docker run --rm \
  -e CONNECTOR_CONFIG=test-connector-config \
  my-image \
  cat /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

In your final Compose setup, you can include the configuration as an `environment:` variable.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports: ['8080:8080']
    environment:
      CONNECTOR_CONFIG: ...
```

`envsubst` is a [GNU tool](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) that replaces `$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` references in text files.  It's very useful for this specific case, but you can do the same work with `sed` or another text-processing tool, especially if you don't have the GNU tools available (in particular if you have an Alpine-based image).

Comment: "COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/"
There was an additional RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/tomcat/bin needed, but then it ran.

Somehow envsubst was not running (probably it was not available or i had a typo) i did sed -i 's/MYVARIABLE/'"$MYVARIABLE"'/g' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml instread.

It was working and now i can change the variable with docker-compose down, editing the compose file and start again. Thats what i wanted, thanks a lot!

Comment: Mode 0755 would be more typical; if you set that permission on your host, `COPY` should preserve the executable bit.